# "Module does not exist in the Haste module map" problem

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

I am building the iOS app with React Native(not with expo), and I get the error with the `react-native-bip39` module installation.

Since I was getting the error below,

`` Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Unable to resolve module `assert` from `/Users/mai/Codes/MyProject/node_modules/react-native-bip39/index.js`: Module `assert` does not exist in the Haste module map ``

I installed `assert` module, but now I get another similar error message.

`` Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Unable to resolve module `stream` from `/Users/mai/Codes/MyProject/node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js`: Module `stream` does not exist in the Haste module map ``

Googling didn't help me much to understand what the Haste module map is and the solution to this problem.

What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` or `yarn` . ? it seems that all packages are not installed

Comment: Yes, I have. My hunch is that some of the modules cannot be used in React Native because these are nodeJS code modules.

Comment: Did you check installed packages are in package.json?